# Select Element EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to avoid using `Ember.Select` as it is now deprecated. I want to use selectize.js to create a UI element similar to:

"Country Selector" in

http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/

Currently, I have a component that has a large number of input elements like:

`{{input val=input_val}}`

to update query parameters passed from the controller. The query parameters are passed to the component via:

`{{component input_val=query_param}}`.

I am want to do something similar but instead for `select` elements. Is there a way to have the `select` elements also dynamically update the query parameters passed in based on what the user selects?

My current idea is to bubble up an action whenever a select element is picked to the controller. However, this seems tedious that the controller should need to handle needing to update a query parameter whenever one gets updated in the component. Is there a more concise way to do this?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit, what query params, are those the url params? and what is the expected behaviour of the select element? is is to update the query params or vice versa ?